# using OpenGL ES Analysis to predict performance on older devices

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es, profiling, instruments

This is screenshot of OpenGL ES Analysis available in Xcodes Instruments.

[image]

I run this analysis on iPhone5S. Is it possible to predict how this same app will do on an older device? I am a little worried because the device utilization is for a small amount of time (0.2s) 48 and 59%. My goal is to include iPhone 4S into the array of devices that can handle my app. I looked at this page to get some info https://browser.primatelabs.com/ios-benchmarks but I am not sure how acurate this is.